# Then files in my project folder used for what?

Tags: iphone

My client needs the non-compiled code. What's that?

My project folder includes:
Classes:of course, the source code.
build:   I don't understand clearly.
imagesrc: I added, include the images of my project.
The others are the nib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to give them everything but a folder called ".build"

- The "Classes" contains your source files
- The "Nibs" are the gui layout you created
- The ".xcodeproj" is the file XCode uses to know what to build
- The ".strings" give you the a list of text written.  (Often used for supporting multiple languages)
- The "info.plist" is a set of standard settings for your app
- The "main.m" file contains information needed for your program to run